# How to group and count the last N results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-postgresql

In Rails, you can use:

> Model.group(:field).count

to yield something like:

> {"a"=>7, "b"=>5, "c"=>3 "d"=>3, "e"=>4}

But how can I **count** ONLY in the **last N lines**, not the entire table, with the **DATABASE** doing the calculations?

Do not work:

Model.limit(100).group(:field).count

> limit will limit the hash output keys not the table lines used

Model.last(100).group(:field).count

> Last returns a Array and raises an error

I'm using:
* Ruby 2.3.3p222
* Rails 4.2.4
* pg 9.5.6

Comment: This should work: `Model.where(id: Model.limit(100).select(:id)).group(:field).count`

Comment: @AbM I can only say: Headshot! Please, use the "answer" do I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, the `limit` is being applied on the grouped instances, not the instances themselves. A simple workaround would be:

`Model.where(id: Model.limit(100).select(:id)).group(:field).count`

Comment: We forgot the **order** to get the LAST results:

> Vote.where(id: Vote.limit(100).select(:id).order(created_at: :desc)).group(:emotion).count

Answer (score 1):

Array objects can also be grouped using `group_by`:

```
grouped = Model.last(100).group_by(&:field).map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }
```

This will return the following matrix:

```
#=> [["Field value 1", value_1_count], ["Field value 2", value_2_count], etc...]
```

Matrix can also be turned into hash:

```
grouped.each_with_object({}) { |value, memo| memo[value[0]] = value[1] }
```

To sum up, try the following:

```
Model.last(100)
  .group_by(&:field)
  .each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), memo| memo[key] = value.length }
```

Comment: You posted a very nice answer and to be fair I must accept its. But I will update the question because I had wrongly omited a very importante information: not in in array, but in SQL (so the basebase will do the calculation.

> Model.group(:field).count

Do the calculation with database , not an array (ruby) calculation.

Can I have this?